# Signing GRUB bootloader

Tags: grub2, boot-loader, uefi

The laptop I recently bought uses UEFI. As an experiment, I think it would be really cool to generate my own keys and use them to sign my bootloader, and also to password protect the bootloader. How would I go about this?